# Filter navigation properties of one-to-many

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3, ios10, ios10.3

I have a model Category with the relationship property articles with is an NSOrderedSet.
Now I want to get all Categories with the articles where a certain condition is fulfilled, in SQL I would write:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Category AS cat
JOIN Article AS art ON art.categoryId = cat.categoryId AND art.gender='m';
```

I tried with:

```
NSPredicate(format: "articles.gender like %@ OR articles.gender = %@", gender.lowercased(), "n")
```

I get the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'

Complete code:

```
    let ctx = self.Context()

    var gender = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "gender_preference") ?? "*"
    if gender.uppercased() == "N" { gender = "*" }

    // Create Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = ArticleCategory.fetchRequest()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "articles.gender like %@ or articles.gender = %@", gender, "n")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    // sort by name
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    do {

        let result = try ctx.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return result

    } catch {

        print(error)

    }

    return []
```

Kind Regards

EDIT:

[image: Model]
[image: Relationship]

Comment: Have you tried with `ANY` ? `NSPredicate(format: "ANY articles.gender like %@ OR articles.gender = %@", gender.lowercased(), "n")`

Comment: Sorry; yes I tried, same for SOME and ALL

Answer (score 0):

I find it's more reliable to use SUBQUERY rather than ANY, ALL, NONE or SOME, particularly with compound clauses.  Fetching Categories where ANY of its articles meet a condition is equivalent to fetching if the count of articles meeting the condition is greater than zero:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(articles, $a, $a.gender like %@ OR $a.gender == %@).@count > 0", gender, "n")
```

Comment: The query compiles, but it's not what I need. I want to filter the articles by the gender. Not get the categories which have more than 0 articles...

Comment: @Mario In which case, fetch Articles not ArticleCategories, and use a simpler predicate: `let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = Article.fetchRequest()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "gender like %@ or gender = %@", gender, "n")`